# including the php page when two variable are set

Tags: php

hello everyone please help me about this problem 
i am sending two variable to the main page and now i want to put the check that if these twi variable are true then called the specific page . here is the sample code

```
http://localhost/admin/admin.php?page=add_user?view=3
```

now i want when page and view are set then call a specific page like this

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])=='add_user' && $_GET['page']=='add_user' ) include("user/add_user.php");
```

in short i want to call this add_user.php when two variable are set up so please suggest for the above line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double switch

*Pseudocode:*

```
switch($_GET['page'])
..
case: 'test':
switch($_GET['view']){
...
}break;
...
```

Comment: do not forget filter input :)

Comment: Don't really understand why you'd tell anyone to use a code like this. This is not something you're supposed to teach someone as correct coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
// the url would be http://localhost/admin/admin.php?page=add_user

if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']=='add_user'){
 include("user/add_user.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(($_GET['page']=='add_user') && ($_GET['view']=='3')){include("user/add_user.php");}
```

but in your GET request, separate variable with &, not a second ?

Comment: Dave's answer brings up something you didn't address: is there a relationship between the variables? Does view have to be '3' for add_user to be loaded?

Comment: He said that 2 variables had to be set. He didn't say what they had to be.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the php files are named after the get request. You could do something like:

```
if((isset($_GET['page'])) && (isset($_GET['view'])))
{
 require_once('user/'. $_GET['page'] . '.php');
}
```

For obviousness: It'd still need to be escaped, or filtered to see if nothing "bad" is being requested.

Comment: localhost/admin/admin.php?page=../../config&view=3

Comment: Yeah, obviously. note "something like". not "exactly as".